# ubuntu php eclipse noob question

Tags: php, eclipse, ubuntu

Hi I am new to php eclipse and I have a question about my eclipse interface..

According to the pictures I saw on the internet, the keyword for php will be colored (mysql_connect, echo...etc). However, every words in my php file are plain black. There are no colored keyword. I am sure my file is saved as .php. How would i solve this problem. Thanks for the help....

**Upadte:**

I installed my eclipse from my software center. I guess that's not the php version. I removed it and tried to download the all-in-one php package. When I unzip and clicked the eclipse file, it said need jdk installation. After I installed my jdk and fired up the eclipse, I can see the php eclipse title in my eclipse, but the keywords are still black....any ideas how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you downloaded the version of eclipse bundled with PHP support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install [PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/) plugin for eclipse

Answer (score 1):

You might want to install [Aptana](http://aptana.com/) (Which is Eclipse based) with the [PHP Plugin](http://docs.aptana.com/docs/index.php/Aptana_PHP_Plugin)